# How to find JSON objects without actually parsing the JSON (regex)

Tags: python, http, parsing

I'm working on filtering a website's data and looking for keywords. The website uses a long JSON body and I only need to parse everything before a base64-encoded image. I cannot parse the JSON object regularly as the structure changes often and sometimes it's cut off.

Here is a snippet of code I'm parsing:

```
<script id="__APP_DATA" type="application/json">{"routeProps":{"b723":{"navDataResource":[{"catalogId":48,"parentCatalogId":null,"icon":"https://bin.bnbstatic.com/image/20200609/bbjy2x.png","catalogName":"New Crypto Listings","total":762,"articles":[{"id":54572,"code":"0ef69e1d334c4d8c9ffbd088843bf2dd","title":"Binance Will List GYEN"},{"id":54548,"code":"e5607624f4614c3f9fd2562c8beb8660","title":"BTG, DEXE \u0026 SHIB Enabled on Binance Isolated Margin"},{"id":54394,"code":"a176d4cfd4c74a7fb8238e63d71c062a","title":"Binance Futures Will Launch USDT-Margined ICP Perpetual Contracts with Up to 25X Leverage"},{"id":54392,"code":"4fa91d953fd0484ab9a48cca0a41c192","title":"Binance Will Open Trading for Internet Computer (ICP)"},{"id":54382,"code":"33b6e8116ce54705ac89e898d1a05510","title":"Binance Will List Internet Computer (ICP)"}],"catalogs":[]},{"catalogId":49,"parentCatalogId":null,"icon":"https://bin.bnbstatic.com/image/20200609/zxgg2x.png","catalogName":"Latest News","total":1164,"articles":[{"id":54649,"code":"2291f02b964f45b195fd6d4685db80bb","title":"Update on Trading Suspension for GYEN"},{"id":54646,"code":"724346d139b041198a441dc149133c7d","title":"Binance Liquid Swap Adds RAMP/BUSD Liquidity Pool"},{"id":54643,"code":"bc9f313c04cc40d2b7e598c831fd721f","title":"Notice on Trading Suspension for GYEN"},{"id":54591,"code":"b3c6998066af43078c63a5498bfd80b1","title":"Binance P2P Supports New Payment Methods for Mongolia"},{"id":54586,"code":"d4418be0b9ea4d1b8e92cbbfe8468a17","title":"Dual Investment (42nd Phase) - Earn Up to 56% APY"}]
```

As you can see, I'm trying to weed out everything except for these:

```
{"id":54382,"code":"33b6e8116ce54705ac89e898d1a05510","title":"Binance Will List Internet Computer (ICP)"}
```

As the JSON is really long and it wouldn't be smart to parse the entire thing, is there a way to find strings like these without actually parsing the JSON object? Ideally, I'd like for everything to be in an array. Will regular expressions work?

The ID is 5 numbers long, the code is 32 characters long, and there is a title.

Thanks a lot in advance

Comment: Why can't you parse it? What do you think the application that uses it does?

Comment: Parse the JSON, then get the `articles` property to get the array you want.

Comment: @Barmar, you should read the post. OP says they can't parse it use because the schema changes often.

Comment: Why is the JSON cut off? Are you trying to read the file while another process is writing it? You need to implement some kind of mutual exclusion so you can be sure you get the complete JSON.

Comment: @Barmar There's a maximum length, and so sometimes the JSON gets cut off

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following will use `string.find()` to step through the string and, if it finds both the start AND end of your target string, it will extract it as a dictionary. If it only finds the start but not the end, it assumes it's a broken or interrupted string and breaks out of the loop as there's nothing further to do.

I'm using the ast module to convert the string to dictionary. This isn't strictly needed to answer the question but I think it makes the end result more usable.

```
import ast

testdata = '{"routeProps":{"b723":{"navDataResource":[{"catalogId":48,"parentCatalogId":null,"icon":"https://bin.bnbstatic.com/image/20200609/bbjy2x.png","catalogName":"New Crypto Listings","total":762,"articles":[{"id":54572,"code":"0ef69e1d334c4d8c9ffbd088843bf2dd","title":"Binance Will List GYEN"},{"id":54548,"code":"e5607624f4614c3f9fd2562c8beb8660","title":"BTG, DEXE \u0026 SHIB Enabled on Binance Isolated Margin"},{"id":54394,"code":"a176d4cfd4c74a7fb8238e63d71c062a","title":"Binance Futures Will Launch USDT-Margined ICP Perpetual Contracts with Up to 25X Leverage"},{"id":54392,"code":"4fa91d953fd0484ab9a48cca0a41c192","title":"Binance Will Open Trading for Internet Computer (ICP)"},{"id":54382,"code":"33b6e8116ce54705ac89e898d1a05510","title":"Binance Will List Internet Computer (ICP)"}],"catalogs":[]},{"catalogId":49,"parentCatalogId":null,"icon":"https://bin.bnbstatic.com/image/20200609/zxgg2x.png","catalogName":"Latest News","total":1164,"articles":[{"id":54649,"code":"2291f02b964f45b195fd6d4685db80bb","title":"Update on Trading Suspension for GYEN"},{"id":54646,"code":"724346d139b041198a441dc149133c7d","title":"Binance Liquid Swap Adds RAMP/BUSD Liquidity Pool"},{"id":54643,"code":"bc9f313c04cc40d2b7e598c831fd721f","title":"Notice on Trading Suspension for GYEN"},{"id":54591,"code":"b3c6998066af43078c63a5498bfd80b1","title":"Binance P2P Supports New Payment Methods for Mongolia"},{"id":54586,"code":"d4418be0b9ea4d1b8e92cbbfe8468a17","title":"Dual Investment (42nd Phase) - Earn Up to 56% APY"}]'

# Create a list to hold the dictionary objects
itemlist = []

# Create variable to keep track of our position in the string
strMarker = 0

#Neverending Loooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooop
while True:

    # Find occurrence of the beginning of a target string
    strStart = testdata.find('{"id":',strMarker)
    if not strStart == -1:
        
        # If we've found the start, now look for the end marker of the string,
        # starting from the location we identified as the beginning of that string
        strEnd = testdata.find('}', strStart)
        
        # If it does not exist, this suggests it might be an interrupted string
        # so we don't do anything further with it, just allow the loop to break
        if not strEnd == -1:

            # Save this marker as it will be used as the starting point
            # for the next search cycle.
            strMarker = strEnd

            # Extract the substring based on the start and end positions, +1 to capture
            # the final '}'; as this string is nicely formatted as a dictionary object
            # already, we are using ast.literal_eval() to turn it into an actual usable
            # dictionary object
            itemlist.append(ast.literal_eval(testdata[strStart:strEnd+1]))

            # We're happy to keep searching so jump to the next loop
            continue

    # If nothing happened to trigger a jump to the next loop, break out of the
    # while loop
    break

# Print out the first entry in the list as a demo
print(str(itemlist[0]))
print(str(itemlist[0]["title"]))
```

Output from this code should be a nice formatted dict:

```
{"id":54572,"code":"0ef69e1d334c4d8c9ffbd088843bf2dd","title":"Binance Will List GYEN"}
Binance Will List GYEN
```

Answer (score 0):

Regular expression should work here. Try matching with the following regular expression. It matches the desired sections, when I try it in https://regexr.com/. Also, regexr helps you understand the regular expression, in case you are new to it.

```
(\{"id":\d{5},"code":".{32}","title":"[^"]*"\})
```

Here is a small sample python script to find all of the sections.

```
import re

pattern='(\{"id":\d{5},"code":".{32}","title":"[^"]*"\})'
string_to_parse='...'
sections = re.findall(pattern, string_to_parse, re.DOTALL)
```

Comment: Unless there's an escaped double quote in the title.

Comment: I don't think you should assume that the id is always exactly 5 digits.